# Mediawiki complaining about open_basedir restriction. How do I solve it?

Tags: php, mediawiki

After a recent update (to system and mediawiki), my Mediawiki is basically completely blank. The database and everything seems to be intact though. After enabling php debug output, I get the following message

> Warning: is_executable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/bin/php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/:/var/lib/mediawiki/) in /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/Wiki.php on line 655

My question is how I go about and resolve this? Simply adding /usr/bin/php to my open_basedir() restriction seems pretty unsafe.

Comment: It would seem extremely silly that PHP is trying to access the PHP executable. I'd go check for some misconfig in your server and Wiki files, starting at line 655 of Wiki.php to see what the hell it's trying to do there and why.

Comment: Hm, did you run `php maintenance/update.php` from the cli after the upgrade?

Comment: Running `php maintenance/runJobs.php` to empty the job queue, and `php maintenance/update.php` to follow your advice didn't modify the problem for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the error occurs in `MediaWiki::doJobs()`, which tries to start a separate PHP process to handle the [job queue](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aJob_queue) asynchronously in the background.  To fix it, you could:

- edit your php.ini to add `/usr/bin/php` to the allowed paths,
- set [`$wgJobRunRate = 0`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgJobRunRate) in your LocalSettings.php to disable automatic job processing entirely, and run [maintenance/runJobs.php](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aRunJobs.php) via cron instead, or
- set [`$wgPhpCli`](//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgPhpCli) to point to some file which is allowed under use_basedir but is *not* an executable program, which should cause the `is_executable()` check to fail silently and force MediaWiki to fall back to synchronous job processing.

Note that the last option, while simplest, can have performance issues, since it means that MediaWiki needs to run background jobs at the end of normal web request processing, potentially increasing page load times.

That said, if you don't want to use the first option, combining the latter two might be safest and most efficient: running background jobs through cron takes them out of the normal request handling path, while setting `$wgPhpCli` to a dummy value ensures that MediaWiki won't try to start background PHP processes for any other purpose either.